# Is there an exploitable relationship between the angles of AB and AC in a triangle when moving point A?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm writing software to dynamically create a random, generated world (civ-esque), populate it with settlements, and draw roads between them. It would be relatively easy to draw roads like [this:](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1if4DnnqMKP0JYwwntpeWrswl0C8sF9q5ELbprxu4e9A/edit?usp=sharing)

However, what I really want is a more "efficient" way of building roads. Something like 
[this:](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1d6__FoIQbSfmjTeCN0Mn5UJ08RqLkPe1m060UOQDfag/edit?usp=sharing)

I appreciate that there must be a relationship between the length of line a and the angles at point x, but I just don't see it. Can anybody help?

Edit: I'm thinking we fix angle BxC at an arbitrary value, perhaps even chosen randomly between a range of values at computation-time to give each intersection some variety.

Comment: Are you saying you want to fix the length of line a and then let the lengths of xB and xC arbitrarily vary?

Comment: The most effective way to connect cities with roads with respect to total road length can be shown to always have three roads at a time meet at $120$ degrees. It might not be the most effective from a logistical standpoint, though.

Comment: I was thinking of fixing angle BxC, perhaps at 120 degrees like @Arthur said, thanks for pointing out my omission.

Comment: If you fix the angle $\measuredangle BxC$, the locus of $x$ is a circular arc between $B$ and $C$. The length $a$ is not fixed at all. Perhaps you could look for a $x$ on the circular arc that minimize $a$?

Comment: @Lewy wrt your answer, that'd then give me the simple iterative process of initially choosing two points and connecting them, then iteratively choosing a point close to the existing roads, and simply connecting that to either the closest settlement or the closest road... That's fantastic :D

Comment: While the optimum for total distance is given by the Fermat point (i.e. $120^\circ$) the "real" optimum wiould also consider how important the various links are. If much more transport occurs between $B$ and $C$ than with $A$, the point $x$ should be moved more and more towards the line $BC$. Similarly, the relative weight of $AB$ versus $AC$ would influence if $x$ should be closer to $B$ or to $C$, possibly $x$ might not be needed at all, and only roads e.g. $AB$ and $BC$ make the optimal solution.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So you're saying that the amount of "indent" or effect A has on the line BC could be relative to the relative size of the settlements at points A, B and C? Brilliant idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you care more about giving some variety to road layout than absolute shortest distance (in which case use Arthur's answer), so how about this:

Connect BC, then connect A to midpoint(BC). Let the length of line $a = A/2 \pm 20\%$, this will give you point x. Then randomly vary the angle of a $\pm 20$ degrees or so, and create lines xC and xB.

This might prove simpler than your idea of fixing BxC, depending on how you are coding things up.